# Change text on page to SQL result from multiple dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sql, ajax

I have an SQL table that is something like the below:

```
  Name  │ Favorite Color │  Age  │  Pet
────────┼────────────────┼───────┼───────
 Rupert │     Green      │  21   │  Cat
  Mike  │      Red       │  19   │  Dog
 Rachel │     Purple     │  24   │  Cat
 Thomas │      Red       │  21   │  Fish
  ...   |      ...       |  ...  |  ...
```

And two dropdowns:

```
<select>
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Choose Pet</option>
    <option>Cat</option>
    <option>Dog</option>
    <option>Fish</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Choose Color</option>
    <option>Red</option>
    <option>Green</option>
    <option>Purple</option>
</select>
```

I want to display the person who likes any given combination from the two dropdowns.

```
//if cat and green selected, print Rupert
//if fish and red selected, print Thomas
//etc
```

I don't really have a game plan for this, I'm kind of stuck. How would I go about this? Some things to note is that I'd ideally want to grab information via SQL rather than hardcode them into the page, so if a person's name is changed, nothing needs to be rewritten.

```
$name = $db->prepare("
    SELECT name
        FROM people
        WHERE color = :col
        AND pet = :pet
");
$name->execute(array(
    ':col' => some value from one dropdown
    ':pet' => some value from another dropdown
));
```

Here's something of an SQL query that would be executed on dropdown change, for example, meaning the actual values of the name don't matter, since it will fetch whatever is correct for the given combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data set will remain as small as it currently is, then you could get the rows and compose a json object out of it and embed it in the page, then you could have javascript lookup the selections and change the name accordingly.

But if you expect the rows will grow to too many to embed in the page, then as you said, you could implement a remote search and send selections to a php script which will then send back the name.

For the first approach you could have:

*JSON*

```
var selections = {
  'Cat-Green': 'Rubert',
  'Dog-Red': 'Mike',
  ... 
};
```

Then you'd better give an id to the selects to make it easy to get their values:

*Markup*

```
<select id="pet" onchange="update();">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Choose Pet</option>
    <option>Cat</option>
    <option>Dog</option>
    <option>Fish</option>
</select>

<select id="color" onchange="update();">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Choose Color</option>
    <option>Red</option>
    <option>Green</option>
    <option>Purple</option>
</select>

<span id="result"></span>
```

Lastly you define a function to update the result:

*JS*

```
function update() {
  var key = $("#pet").val() + '-' + $("#color").val();
  $("#result").text(selections[key]);
}
```

On the backend, when serving the page, you'd parse the json object like so:

*Whole script*

```
<?php
// create your db link, then
$query  = "SELECT * FROM `favorites` LIMIT 50"; // just in case
$result = mysqli($link, $query);
$array  = array(); // empty array to be filled with data
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  // Name  │ Favorite Color │  Age  │  Pet
  $array[$row['Pet'] . '-' . $row['Color']] = $row['Name'];
}
$json = json_encode($array); // convert array to json string
// we are done. Next we close PHP and start outputing HTML, JS and our JSON
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  ...
  <script src=" ... remember to add jquery ... ></script>
  <script>
    var selections = <?php echo $json; ?>;
    ...
    function update ...
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <select id="pet" onchange="update();">
  ...
</body>
</html>
```

[Link to jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ulIGEsES/2/edit) with hardcoded json hardcoded.

Comment: Thanks! This gives me a good fundamental approach to work with. Just curious: if the names of the pets and names of the colors are dynamic (as in they can be changed via SQL), this method won't work since combinations are essentially hardcoded. Is there a way JSON can interface with SQL so I can initialize the first snippet of code to elements from SQL?

Comment: @riista Well the assumption is you build the JSON object out of the contents of DB table at page load time. If you are worried about them getting changed after a user has loaded the page, then you have to use the remote search approach, but if the data is not that volatile and only changes occasionally, you could assume the chances of a user having outdated data is not high (assuming someone does not leave a tab open for days on end).